# Make my website responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a website which i want to make responsive (hope that is the right term, in order of it to adjust to all screens and not be modified by zoom -in or zoom - out by mouseover).
The code of body is the following:

```
<body>
  <div id = "zoom">
     ......
   <div>
```

My css is:

```
#zoom{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So my idea as it can be seen above was to put everything in the body inside a div and then arrange the div like above which did not work.. Any ideas on how can this be implemented?

Comment: Why are doing this yourself? Why not use a library like Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/  or Zurb Foundation? http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: If yo want to have responsive website, you should use responsive css frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation,.. or use atMedia" css rule.

Comment: Agreed, if you are new to responsive web start with frameworks like Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers i did not know about Bootstrap i will search about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd research about `media queries` if I were you. Or like other people have said, learn how to use Bootstrap.

Comment: If i do it like you mentioned, when i zoon- in using mouseover the site collapses (meaning that it does not stay in the format of 100%)

Comment: You can try using `100vh`. Although this is known to be buggy on iDevices and therefore bad practice. It's pretty neat apart from these facts.